# How to represent graphically the relationship of $Z$ and $\gamma$ to $W_3$ and $B^0$?

Tags: standard-model, electroweak

How to represent graphically the relationship of $Z$ and $\gamma$ to $W_3$ and $B^0$ ?

I made these two schematics below, but I'm not sure which one is correct, nor if we we should put $W_3$ or $B^0$ in $x$ axis or in $y$ axis.

-If this would be the schematic of the left, it could not work, since $Z$ has a positive y axis, thus $-\sin_{\theta_W}$ (*negative*) would expect the $Z$ to be at negative $y-axis$.

-If this would be the schematic of the right, it could not work, since the $x$ value of $Z$ is negative.

-If $B^0$ would be in the $x$ axis, it would not work since it represents the $x$ axis for the rotation matrix.

Thus, none of my schematics seem to work

[image]

A third and fourth are the following

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourth diagram is the appropriate one if you want to visualize this relationship as a rotation.